# Snow Leopard and NAS share

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, network-shares, nas

I bought a BlackArmor 220 from Seagate. When I start Snow Leopard the NAS shows up with its full name under shares. The problem is that when I click the NAS only a folder BA_Backup shows up, all the other folders, I created, don't. When I click the NAS, it says I'm connected as "guest".
I mean I can connect by "Go to server" and additionally add the folders to the user startup objects, so they show up when I start my Mac, but when the NAS already shows up, why can't I configure it?  Where can I change this?

Comment: I have the exact same problem, but cannot vote up. Do anyone have some info?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that if the NAS is enabled for Time Machine backup support, that supersedes everything else.

Log into the NAS as an admin, then select Storage -> Backup Manager.

On the left side of the page, under the "Backup Server" heading, select "Time Machine".  Disable that, and all your CIFS shares will now appear when you browse.